# 画像を2次元FFTで処理したいのですが、結果が正しくない気がします……

Tags: java

スケーリングはパワースペクトルの平方根の対数を取ったのですが、ImageJなどのプログラムで二次元FFTした結果と見比べると何かが違う気がします。どこかコードに間違えているところがあるのでしょうか？
　ちなみにFFT用のライブラリは、[「大浦版FFTのJava移植」](http://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA046927/fft4gjava.html)を使用しています。

例：
元画像(lena)→[image: lena]
このプログラムで処理した結果→[image: FFT_1]
ImageJ→[image: FFT_2]

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class show_resolution{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        if(args.length < 1) return;
        try{
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(args[0]));
            int w = image.getWidth(), h = image.getHeight();
            double[] image_data = new double[w * h * 2];
            // データを配列に代入する
            for(int y = 0; y < h; ++y){
                for(int x = 0; x < w; ++x){
                    int color = image.getRGB(x, y);
                    int r = (color & 0xff0000) >> 16;
                    int g = (color & 0xff00) >> 8;
                    int b = color & 0xff;
                    image_data[(x + y * w) * 2] = 0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b;
                    image_data[(x + y * w) * 2 + 1] = 0.0;
                }
            }
            // 二次元FFT
            fft2d(image_data, w, h);
            // パワースペクトルに変換
            power_spectral(image_data, w, h);
            // 象限入れ替え
            swap_quadrants(image_data, w, h);
            // 正規化
            normalization(image_data, w, h);
            // 出力
            for(int y = 0; y < h; ++y){
                for(int x = 0; x < w; ++x){
                    int Y = (int)(image_data[(x + y * w)] * 255);
                    if(Y > 255) Y = 255;
                    if(Y < 0) Y = 0;
                    image.setRGB(x, y, 0x010101 * Y + 0xff000000);
                }
            }
            String file_name = args[0].substring(0, args[0].lastIndexOf(".")) + "_FFT.png";
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(file_name));
        }catch(Exception error){
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // 正規化
    static void normalization(double[] a, int w, int h){
        double min = a[0], max = a[0];
        for(int k = 1; k < w * h; ++k){
            min = Math.min(min, a[k]);
            max = Math.max(max, a[k]);
        }
        double diff = max - min;
        for(int k = 0; k < w * h; ++k){
            a[k] = (a[k] - min) / diff;
        }
    }
    // 象限入れ替え
    static void swap_quadrants(double[] a, int w, int h){
        int hw = w / 2, hh = h / 2;
        double[] b = new double[w * h];
        for(int y = 0; y < hh; ++y){
            for(int x = 0; x < hw; ++x){
                b[(y + hh) * w + x] = a[y * w + (x + hw)];  //第1象限
                b[(y + hh) * w + (x + hw)] = a[y * w + x];  //第2象限
                b[y * w + (x + hw)] = a[(y + hh) * w + x];  //第3象限
                b[y * w + x] = a[(y + hh) * w + (x + hw)];  //第4象限
            }
        }
        for(int k = 0; k < w * h; ++k){
            a[k] = b[k];
        }
    }
    // パワースペクトルに変換
    static void power_spectral(double[] a, int w, int h){
        for(int y = 0; y < h; ++y){
            for(int x = 0; x < w; ++x){
                double re = a[(x + y * w) * 2];
                double im = a[(x + y * w) * 2 + 1];
                double norm = re * re + im * im;
                if(norm != 0.0) norm = Math.log(norm) / 2;
                a[x + y * w] = norm;
            }
        }
    }
    // 2次元FFT
    static void fft2d(double[] a, int w, int h){
        double[] b = new double[w * h * 2];
        // 水平方向のFFT
        for(int y = 0; y < h; ++y){
            fft1d(a, w * 2, y * w * 2);
        }
        // 転置操作
        transpose(a, b, w, h);
        // 垂直方向のFFT
        for(int x = 0; x < w; ++x){
            fft1d(b, h * 2, x * h * 2);
        }
        // 転置操作
        transpose(b, a, h, w);
    }
    // 1次元FFT
    static void fft1d(double[] a, int n, int p){
        double[] temp = new double[n];
        for(int k = 0; k < n; ++k){
            temp[k] = a[p + k];
        }
        FFT4g fft = new FFT4g(n);
        fft.rdft(1, temp);
        temp[1] = 0;
        for(int k = 0; k < n; ++k){
            a[p + k] = temp[k];
        }
    }
    // 行列の転置
    static void transpose(double[] src, double[] dst, int w, int h){
        for(int y = 0; y < h; ++y){
            for(int x = 0; x < w; ++x){
                int p = x + y * w;
                int q = y + x * h;
                dst[q * 2    ] = src[p * 2];
                dst[q * 2 + 1] = src[p * 2 + 1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ImageJ で処理した際のコントラスト設定は `auto` ですか？

Comment: zipを解凍してそのまま起動→画像ドロップ→Process->FFT->FFTといった手順で他は全くいじっていません。

Comment: 今、YSR さんのコードをコンパイルして、lena 画像を処理してみたのですが、、若干の違いはあるものの、ImageJ の画像と同じになりました。こちらの Java のバージョンは `1.9.0-ea` です。

Comment: こちらは`1.8.0_65`ですが、そこで差が生まれるものでしょうか？　この画像を私のコードで変換した結果を、画像アップロードしてURLで教えて下さいますと嬉しいです。http://i.imgur.com/vqWqLCp.jpg

Comment: はい、こちらです。http://i.imgur.com/6mJnSFt.png

Comment: ありがとうございます。貴方が先ほど上げた画像は、こちらで実行した結果と一致しました。ただ、同じ元画像をImageJに掛けるとこうなって(http://i.imgur.com/hX6Nxi9.png)、明るさが何故か違う、と言うか第2・4象限が暗くないんですよね……